# Is there anyplace to download org.springframework.web?

Tags: maven, spring-framework-beans

I have a java web app that uses org.springframework.web : 3.0.0.RELEASE.  The problem is this version registers a number of vulnerabilities when I do a CNARS scan.

When I go to the Maven repository at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/org.springframework.web - none of the newer versions can be located.

Does anyone know where to get later org.springframework.web libraries?

Thanks

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web

Comment: The location is: https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/  Apart from that I strongly recommend to upgrade that app.... because it's really old.

Comment: Thanks - and you're both right.  It is old :)